# Declaring object via pointer inline after specyfing namespace

Tags: c++, pointers, object, namespaces

When I type this:

```
Cat *cat = new Cat();
```

and put the "using namespace Namespace;" at the top, it works. 
But, if I try this:

```
Namespace :: Cat *cat = new Cat();
```

It doesn't work. So if anyone could could explain it I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Because you need to specify the namespace of `Cat` *everywhere*. Also, avoid `new` if possible, especially if you're a beginner.

Comment: @juanchopanza how to avoid `new`, especially if your are a beginner?

Comment: @Satus Simply by not using it. It is like asking "how to use `new`, if you are a beginner". In this code, `new` is completely gratuitous.

Comment: `Namespace::Cat *cat = new Namespace::Cat();`

Comment: @juanchopanza well, a beginner usually learns how to use c++ by writing code and using language's tools. And since `new` is one of the core instruments of c++, there is no possible way for a beginner to avoid using it.

Comment: @Satus That is one of many ways a beginner can learn. But to say that there is no possible way for a beginner to avoid using `new` is complete  nonsense. It is easy enough to avoid. In fact, in most cases it is easier to avoid it than to use it.

Comment: @Satus - in many cases you can use static and automatic storage instead of dynamic. If you need data in dynamic storage - nowadays - use `std::make_unique` and `std::make_shared`. Many projects today see explicit using of `new` as violation of their coding standard...

Comment: @Satus You're wasting your time the trend now is don't use `new` and `delete` and since the King said so [CppCon 2015: Bjarne Stroustrup “Writing Good C++14”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OEu9C51K2A), it is so. Saying otherwise you're a heretic nowdays. IMHO banning new and delete is an attemp to popularize C++, nothing more. Life rules are simpler though, with a knife you can cut bread and you can also cut your self. So learn how to use the knife.

Comment: `Namespace::Cat cat;`

Comment: @PiotrNycz Are you saying that using c++14 memory managment features without getting practice with manual allocation and not knowing how it works internally it a better way for C++ programmer? I mean, we are talking about a beginner here. While I agree that static memory is highly preferable, you can't use it for any possible problems. All I want to say is that a beginner should know how to use manual memory allocation as it is an important and significant tool of C++.

Comment: @Satus The point is that if you're such a beginner that you don't even understand dynamic memory allocation, when you shouldn't be using it. When you figure out that you need it, then you should explore the options. But often people come to C++ thinking the only way you can instantiate an object is by calling `new`. Also, using `new` over standard library memory management techniques should be considered expert, not beginner stuff. Would you ask people to learn assembly before they learn how to write a for loop?

Comment: @juanchopanza Don't understand it -> don't use it? That is not a way to learn. Beginner can't "figure out that you need it", almost 100% times they don't, that doesn't mean they should learn it and try using it. Did you ever see a C++ programmer saying "I never used new and delete since I didn't need it"?

Comment: @Satus juanchopanza has a good point with `But often people come to C++ thinking the only way you can instantiate an object is by calling new`. I too was this in the past. Everything not being a stack variable was new (and malloc), taught by some more experienced programmer (at least he was back then), but I never heard anything else from him. I knew some obscure thing named vector existed, but it took (too) long to actually google it, because I was comfortable with using new all the time. And things like smart pointers etc.etc., in my mind, only existed in other languages, but not C++.

Comment: Addition: ... so I wasn't interested what a smart pointer actually is.

Comment: @Satus You seem to think that learning by trying out random things that one doesn't understand is productive. I have many years of experience that say otherwise. So, we won't agree on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short answer

If you don't write `using namespace Namespace` you need to specify the namespace in **every** occurrence of the name `Cat`.

```
Namespace::Cat *cat = new Namespace::Cat();
```

#### Explanation

When you write `Cat` without the namespace specification the compiler searches for `Cat` in the current scope and namespaces, in this case `Cat` is in a different namespace so it cannot be found unless you tell the compiler to look into that namespace too by adding `using namespace Namespace;`.

The other option you have is to always qualify its name by writing the namespace in front of every occurrence of your type, `Namespace::Cat`. This way the compiler knows where to look.

The second method is usually considered better since you have less chances of name collisions.

See [Name Lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup) for more details on how the compiler searches for names.